# How to find the maximum likelihood estimator of $f(y;\alpha)=5\alpha^5y^{-6}$?

Tags: parameter-estimation

How to find the maximum likelihood estimator of 
$$f(y;\alpha)=\frac{5\alpha^5}{y^6}$$
for 
$$0<\alpha\leq y<\infty.$$
Otherwise,
$$f(y;\alpha)=0.$$
I have tried, but my result is $\hat{\alpha}_{MLE} = +\infty$. Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not right, and the trouble is that you wrote the PDF incorrectly. The correct PDF to be maximized over $\alpha$ is $$f(y;\alpha)=5\alpha^5y^{-6}\mathbf 1_{0<\alpha\leqslant y}.$$ Can you find the value $\hat\alpha$ which maximizes this?

Comment: You should solve $max \mathcal{L}$ subject to $0<\alpha\leq min{y_1,...y_n}$

Comment: @MaxGaussian Indeed.

Comment: Thanks, bro. I came up with $$\hat{\alpha}_{MLE}=\min{Y_i}$$